# Have user pick a contact and get the contact's mobile number

Tags: android, contacts

I'm trying to have a user pick a contact from his contacts list so that I can do some processing on that number.  My code to launch the list-picking activity is

```
    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  
            Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI);  
    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

and my receiving code is

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (reqCode) {
    case (PICK_CONTACT) :
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();  
            Set<String> keys = extras.keySet();  
            Iterator<String> iterate = keys.iterator();  
            while (iterate.hasNext()) {  
                String key = iterate.next();  
                Log.v(TAG, key + "[" + extras.get(key) + "]");  
            }  
            Uri result = data.getData();  
            Log.v(TAG, "Got a result: "  
                + result.toString());  
        }
    break;
    }
}
```

but the extras bundle does not have any names or phone numbers in it.  How can I get the result of a user's selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getData() call contains the Uri that you can open a cursor on. Try the following:

```
   Uri resultUri = data.getData();
   Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(resultUri, null, null, null, null);
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       // Found results process cursor
   }
```

Comment: Cool!  Is there a way to get a list of the data contained in the cursor?

Comment: Thank you!  This worked with the following addition:

      String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NUMBER));